# Google Cloud Print - Query number limit

Tags: google-api, google-cloud-print

I need to do a lot of google cloud print queries.
I got this error "HTTP Error 503: Too many requests".

In API Console I can't find "Google cloud print"

Is there any solution?

Comment: You ever get an answer on this @Admdebian ??

Comment: no, but I get a 502 gateway error from google every 2 hours

Comment: I am working on Google cloud print and facing the same issue, Have you got any solution ? Do you know the exact limit with this API ?

Comment: I don't know the exact limit, I'm sorry

Comment: What api are you having problems with?